# In Shopify, how do I add mouseover to a non-product page?

Tags: plugins, hover, shopify, mouseover

I am building my site in shopify.  On the "about us" page I have photos of each team member.  I would like to be able to click on the photo to show a JPG (which is a postcard of employee title and interesting facts).  Is there a way to add a mouseover feature on an image that is not a product?  We are using the minimal theme. As point of reference we got this idea from www.scoutbags.com/about-us
On that site they use a hover feature to change the photo and then a click through to the postcard.  We are skipping the second photo to try to keep it simple/doable.

Comment: Have a look at prettyphoto - `http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/`

Answer (score 0):

Here's info on how to enable lightboxes on your images.

https://docs.shopify.com/themes/customization/colors-images-and-video/add-lightbox-to-images

To enable images on your About Us page, you need to edit page.liquid. Find the div element that contains your page content. To the opening `<div>` tag, add `class="rte"`.

Make sure you follow the rest of the steps on that tutorial.